# best way to filter and search with vue3&django_rest

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuex, vuejs3

I'm new to vue and Django ,I want to implement a search component for a e-commerce project and filter the results as user want. i spent some time to find a proper way and here is what i understand so far:

- front solution: for vue3 i can use vuex store and computed properties to implement search and filter the search results for example (https://softauthor.com/vuejs-composition-api-search-bar-using-computed-properties/#disqus_thread) the question is: 1) is it a good solution still when scaling, to store all products in vuex and filter and search them when search results are containing for example more than 500 or more products...
- backend solution: with Django rest_framework: one way is to send the search result from Django and send a request for every filter and search option that maybe valid for getting highest discount in all products but not all cases i think...the question i have here is : 2) is it better to do the search through django and limit the number of result sending back instead of vue solution...

finally, should i mix the ways and use searching in all products through Django and some other conditions with vue

I saw lots of questions for search and filtering but didn't find one to explain my questions and i know i didn't narrow it down and i don't really know if I'm looking at it in the right way or not so please bare with me, if anyone can help me with an answer or **some references** to follow would be appreciated..thx

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view is always better to do filtering backend. On backend you can control everything. Doing filtering on frontend on maybe 100000 items is going to be slower than letting django handle that.
Take a look at [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html) which is a good filtering package that goes well with django-rest-framework.